# Работа с полями экземпляра C#

Tags: c#

Есть класс Options с несколькими листиками и другой класс Form1. Создан экземпляр класса Options в классе Form1. Как начать работу с полями этого экземпляра(Array, ColorPenBrush, Thickness)?

```
class Options
{
    public List<Point> Array { get; set; }
    public List<Color> ColorPenBrush { get; set; }
    public List<String> Thickness { get; set; }
}

class Form1
{
    Options options = new Options();
    //далее пример работы
    Point point1;
    point1.X = 100;
    point1.Y = 200;
    options.Array.Add(point1);
}
```

Comment: Вы обращаетесь к Array, однако не видно где вы создаёте экземпляр списка...т е нет new List<Point>

Comment: @Виталий, да, я понимаю. Как тогда это должно выглядеть? options.Array = new List<Point>(); не подходит.

Comment: Напишите это в классе options

Comment: @Виталий, все равно не дает.

Comment: Сделайте конструктор для Options, а в нем инициализацию Ваших списков.

Comment: Я похоже разобрался. Мы можем обращаться к options.Array и прочим только в методе. Непонятно только почему.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы не сделали инициализацию своих списков в классе Options. Это можно сделать например в его конструкторе:

```
class Options
    {
        public List<Point> Array { get; set; }
        public List<Color> ColorPenBrush { get; set; }
        public List<String> Thickness { get; set; }

        public Options()
        {
            Array = new List<Point> ();
            ColorPenBrush = new List<Color>();
            Thickness = new List<String>();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

В новых версиях C# существуют [Инициализаторы автосвойств](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-6#auto-property-initializers):

```
class Options
{
    public List<Point> Array { get; set; } = new List<Point>();
    public List<Color> ColorPenBrush { get; set; } = new List<Color>();
    public List<String> Thickness { get; set; } = new List<String>();
}
```